# Wobbling DC motor head

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, gears, bearings

I have used 250 watt DC motor, for DIY electric potters wheel. Motor rated with RPM 3300 and geared reduction to 330 RPM. The issue I am facing is wobbling of the motor head. This issue is with the motor head/shaft and not the disc. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you tell if the motor shaft is untrue or the gear that is attached to it?

Comment: Does the motor shaft wobble under no load condition? Or is it wobbling only when it's transmitting power through the gears?

Comment: Useca dial gauge to measure the run-out of the shaft and the gear.